# Get user data from database codeignter

Tags: sql, session

I have two tables in one database, table one called: ci_admin, and table two called active_ingredient.

I want to get user data from the active_ingredient table where user_id equals admin_id from ci_admin table using the current user session.

this code, get data for all user, I need the data inserted by the user only:

```
        $wh =array();
        $SQL ='SELECT * FROM active_ingredient';
        $wh[] = "SELECT 1
        FROM   ci_admin
        WHERE  ci_admin.admin_id = active_ingredient.user_id";

        if(count($wh)>0)
        {               $WHERE = implode(' and ',$wh);
            return $this->datatable->LoadJson($SQL,$WHERE);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->datatable->LoadJson($SQL);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will help you.

```
    $this->db->select('ai.*,ca.*'); 
    $this->db->from('active_ingredient ai');
    $this->db->join('ci_admin ca', 'ca.admin_id = ai.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where($data); //pass the session data for exact filter
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's not working. please note that I'm using datatable. and this is what happens when applying your code:
DataTables warning: table id=active_datable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: Send screenshots for better understand